# GitHub Desktop & Synology 6.2

Tags: git, github, synology

I am trying to use the latest Github Desktop with Synology git serverbit I am getting an authentication failure error. I have created a public key and uploaded it to my Synology user and renamed it to autorized_keys as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/walkerjeffd/374750c366605cd5123d) but I am still getting the same auth error. Changed the permissions of the folder as well. How can I commit and push to Synology? I am running DSM 6.2.

**EDIT**: Have been trying what is [recommended here](https://blog.aaronlenoir.com/2018/05/06/ssh-into-synology-nas-with-ssh-key/) but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I followed the second tutorial and set up the public key. One thing not mentioned is the Allow/Block ip addresses in Control Panel > Securities. I have added the ip range of my local network and everything works great now.